# HazelcastSessionRepository - custom session ID

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast, spring-session

I need to use custom session ID for the new sessions created by  HazelcastSessionRepository`.

However, `HazelcastSessionRepository` uses `private final class HazelcastSession`.

Therefore it is not possible to simply extend `HazelcastSessionRepository` and override `createSession` method outside the package `org.springframework.session.hazelcast`.

Unfortunately, I can see just these 2 options here:

1. Create own implementation of SessionRepository - just copy of the HazelcastSessionRepository indeed with createSession method changed
2. Create an extension of HazelcastSessionRepository (with createSession method overridden) within my project in org.springframework.session.hazelcast package.

Is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to create your own session ids yet, but feel free to open a feature request.